# Outer join 3 sheets using formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 3 tables in 3 sheets. The **email** column is where the data is identified. Which means the emails will be unique in the expected results sheet after joining

[To make a copy of the sheet click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mtd0oNMCJFjCMsypcBr7YQqMjYONzjEKAuk1s7Q7n1E/copy)
[To view the sheet click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mtd0oNMCJFjCMsypcBr7YQqMjYONzjEKAuk1s7Q7n1E/edit?usp=sharing)

**First Sheet**

```
First Name
Last Name
Email
Phone
Childs First Name
Child Last Name
DOB
Photo Permission
Allergies
Additional Info
Additional Contact
Teacher Name(s)
Sibling First Name
Sibling Last Name
DOB2
Allergies 2
Additional Info 2
Photo Permission 2
How did hear?
```

**Second**

```
Second-First Name
Second-Last Name
Second-Phone
Email
Second-Message
```

**Third**

```
Third-First Name
Third-Last Name
Email
```

I have tried with

```
=FILTER({First!A2:B,
 VLOOKUP(First!C2:C, {Second!A2:A, Second!B2:D}, {2,3,4}, false)},
 First!C2:C<>"")
```

But I need to ensure all 3 sheets are joined and the expected result look like
Expected
[image: image.png]

First
[image: image.png]
Second
[image: image.png]

Third
[image: image.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three formulas in cyan on the tab called MK.Help in [this editable copy of your sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yv_FG_GT5ZqNVP8a6vLFtQco-XcdP-3m35_3TMVxY84/edit#gid=1918216648):

This is the one for the second set of names:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({Second!A1:E1;ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C,{Second!D:D,Second!A:E},{2,3,4,5,6},0)),COUNTA(C2:C),5);FILTER(Second!A2:E,Second!D2:D<>"",ISNA(MATCH(Second!D2:D,C2:C,0)))})
```

That do what you're hoping?